# How to replace the . and space with <br> tag in php

Tags: php, wordpress, string, preg-replace

Hello I want to replace . which is coming with space like

$data = 'Hello **xzx.** Thank manresa.org';

I am using like

```
str_replace(". ","<br><br>",$data);
```

But it is not working for me.

when I replace only . which is not with space

$data = 'Hello **xzx.**Thank manresa.org';

```
 str_replace(".","<br><br>",$data);
```

result is:->

```
Hello xzx

Thank manresa

org
```

so I want to break string which has dot . with space.how can I do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression (along with `preg_replace()`).

```
$string = 'Hello xzx. Thank manresa.org';
$pattern = '/\.\s/';
$replacement = '<br />';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Output:

```
Hello xzx
Thank manresa.org
```

The expression simply matches a period (`\.`) and then any white-space character (`\s`).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following code. Hope that suits your requirment. :)

```
$string = 'Hello xzx. Thank manresa.org';
$pattern = '/\./';
$replacement = '< br />< br />';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Hello xzx

Thank manresa